# How does Google get the site's description, when there is no description present in the HTML?

Tags: google-search

I go to Google and type "tumblr".  The first result is www.tumblr.com.  It says

```
"A feature rich and free blog hosting platform offering professional and fully customizable templates,...."
```

Then I go to www.tumblr.com, and look at the HTML source code, but I cant find that description, how can that be?  And I noticed this is true for lots of additional sites.  Where does Google get descriptions from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624)

> We use a number of different sources for this information, including descriptive information in the title and meta tags for each page. We may also use publicly available information—for instance, anchor text or listings from the Open Directory Project (DMOZ)—or create rich snippets based on markup on the page.

In this case, [it most likely came from DMOZ](http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=https://www.tumblr.com/)